# I could not transfer data from datagrid column to an array in C# for textbox suggestion collection data

Tags: c#, c++

i am trying to put the values of a certain column from a dataGrid to a string hence
i am getting this error like "**An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'** ".
What i am trying to do is to put that collection of data to a collection that will suggest what in it in a textbox.

heres my code; I hope there will be someone who could help me.

just a newbee here, sorry i might look stupid for this query [pizz]

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    xxxx[row.Index] = row.Cells[3].Value.ToString().Trim();
}
for (int x = 10; x <= dataGridView1.RowCount - 1; x++)
{
    collection.Add(xxxx[x].ToString());

}

Search.AutoCompleteCustomSource = collection;
Search.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
Search.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
```

i even tried this method on getting values from the column;

```
for (int x = 1; x <= dataGridView1.RowCount - 1; x++)
{
    xxxx[x] = dataGridView1.Rows[x].Cells[searchChokoy].Value.ToString(); 
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i already figured out what's the reason why i could not get the data from the datagrid it just that i have to put -2 on the condition on forloops because the source file is a csv file tho and indexing is quite a bit different.

Anyways i just tried my luck here, Thanks!